# The Worker Process (w3wp) crashes in Windows 10 and Servers while using Oracle OracleDataNotify.OnNotificaton

Tags: w3wp

We are using the concept of Oracle Data Notification in dotNet.
WorkerProcess w3wp is crashing whenever there is an insertion in USER_CHANGE_NOTFICATION_REGS table in the windows 10 and windows Server operating system.

**Following is the code** 
    OracleDependency dep= new OracleDependency(cmd);
    dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OracleDataNotify.OnNotificaton);

**Following is the Exception Details.**
System.OverflowException Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDependency.OnChangeOpsCallback_fn(String id, IntPtr opsErrCtx, IntPtr opsChgNTFNDesc, NotiVal notiVal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the Oracle Data Notification is working in the Windows 7 Operating system but in latest OS version like win10 and win2012 server OS w3wp is getting crashed.
But the issue got fixed by installing the Latest version of Oracle Client i.e.,2.122.1.0.